# syntax error (missing operator) in query expression on Cascading Dropdownlist in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have been working around two hours to fix this error and I could not find where that actual error is.

I am setting up a cascading dropdown list combobox, this is an AfterUpdate event. Basically I have a ComboBox on the form in Access called SUBPROYECTO but this list depends on another combo box called PROYECTOS, this is the 3rd combo box in the secuence, I mean, PROYECTOS also depends on another combo box called CLIENTE.
The fist cascading works fine, I am able to see ONLY the PROYECTOS that matches the CLIENTE, but when I try to do the same on SUBPROYECTOS I get this error:

syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'tblSubProyectos.SUBPROYECTO  WHERE PROYECTO = 4 ORDER BY SUBPROYECTO'.

The code in VB is

```
    Private Sub cboProyecto_AfterUpdate()

Me.cboSubProyecto.RowSource = "SELECT tblSubProyectos.idSubProyecto, tblSubProyectos.SUBPROYECTO " & _
" WHERE PROYECTO = " & Nz(Me.cboProyecto) & _
" ORDER BY SUBPROYECTO"

Me.cboSubProyecto = Null
cboProyecto.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the data type of the PROYECTO string ? If yes, then you need to specify single quote in WHERE clause above

Comment: Your query needs a `FROM` clause ... `FROM tblSubProyectos`.  Build and test your query with the Access query designer.

Comment: `SELECT fields FROM your table WHERE some condition ORDER BY some field`